# something wrong with asin() function

Tags: java, android, math, trigonometry

I have these two lines of code:

```
var[1] =var[2].multiply(var[3]).multiply(var[4]).multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.sin(var[5].doubleValue())));
    var[5] =new BigDecimal(Math.asin(var[1].divide(var[2],precision,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).divide(var[3],precision,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).divide(var[4],precision,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()));
```

I am giving values for var[2],var[3],var[4] and var[5] to get var[1].

Equation used is

```
var[1]=var[2]*var[3]*var[4]*sin(var[5])
```

Then I am trying to get var[5] using var[1] I just got and the same values of other variables, it gives me a wrong number and I can't see why

Comment: What are your values for var[2..5]? (And why don't your vars have better names?)

Comment: So tp be explicit... You are trying to reverse the arithmetic that you stored in var[1] to get the original value of var[5]?

Comment: using: var[2]=2,var[3]=2,var[4]=2,var[5]=2 I get var[1]=7.27438 and then I use var[1]=7.27438, var[2]=2,var[3]=2,var[4]=2 to get var[5] back but it gives me different value: 1.14159

Comment: You should never assume that a built in function is wrong when your code fails to behave as expected.  A bug would have been found long ago.  It's you and your code that's wrong - first, last, and always.

Comment: I am not saying that my code is right. I just don't where it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewrite**

I am cleaning out some arithmetic cobwebs, but:

```
Math.asin(Math.sin(1)) == ~1
Math.asin(Math.sin(3.14 / 2)) == ~3.14 / 2  // 1.57
Math.asin(Math.sin(3.14)) == ~0
```

Like [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29) says the results for Math.asin() are bound between -Pi/2 and Pi/2...

So your answer appears "incorrect" since it is bound inside this range.

**Alternate**

The most asin() will return is: Pi/2 = 1.57

And 2 > 1.57 so:

2 - 1.57 = 0.43

1.57 - 0.43 = 1.14

therefore: 
2 = 1.14

Comment: what if my 2 is in radians? So this prevents from vonverting

Comment: math.asin(math.sin()) this looks strange hopefully maybe it will work

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your numbers are in Radians and not Degrees?

Try converting to radians: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is in radians or not because I should get the same value which I used to get var[1]. If you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that

var[5] = asin(var[1]/var[2]/var[3]/var[4])

rather than

var[5] = asin(var[1] divided by (var[2]*var[3]*var[4]))

I hope i understood your code correctly.

Comment: I think this is correct as to be:var[5] = asin(var[1]/var[2]/var[3]/var[4]) ir should be : var[5] =new BigDecimal(Math.asin(var[1].divide(var[2].divide(var[3].divide(var[4]))).doubleValue()));

Comment: Damn, i'm tired, i missed some brackets.